# Offset image mouseover

Tags: html, css

I am trying to do something similar to the way this price list works with regard to the mouseover, and big image underneath changing.  I cannot find what this is called, can anyone point me in the right direction?

http://www.anyjunk.co.uk/rubbish-removal-prices

Comment: Search for **css sprites** and **css image replacement**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like just a basic `onmouseover` event. You could do the same with something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function changeImage(imageFile)
    {
        document.getElementById('img1').src = imageFile;
    }
</script>
<div id="div1" onmouseover="changeImage('image2.jpg')">Mouse over this</div>
<img src="image1.jpg" id="img1" />
```

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TXgLv/4/) as an example.

Comment: Thank you for replying so quickly, I thought it was something like that, but I couldn't see anywhere anything that was it exactly.  I was hoping to do it without javascript if possible, as I need it work well on ipads/iphone.  I have 10 diffrent items that need to mouseover and show big image..would this still work?

Comment: iPad and iPhone have Javascript engines. This should work fine on those. They just don't handle Flash so well. Take a look at the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TXgLv/4/). You can add any number of items you want.